# Get number of connected users on server as sum and export to a csv which name is date & time when script was executed

Tags: powershell

i try to make a script that runs and exports the number of connected users (the sum of it in numbers) to a csv file which name is the date & time when the script was executed. i want to get the average users by day on a remotedesktop server, so that we know if we need to set up more server with loadbalancing. i have this code below, but this exports the users and would like only the sum of the users and the thing qith the filename of the csv

```
Get-QUser | Export-csv -Path C:\ConnectedUsersLog\ConnectedUsers.csv
```

Comment: What is `Get-QUser`? Please link to the module you're using

Answer (score 0):

To make a file name with the date code you could do something like. . .

```
$Filename = (Get-Date).ToShortDateString().Replace('/','-') + ".txt"
```

You could use performance counters for Terminal Services to get the count of logged on useers.

```
Get-Counter -Counter  "\Terminal Services\Active Sessions" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty CounterSamples | Select-Object -ExpandProperty CookedValue
```

Comment: thank you very much for your help. the part with the file name works great. the part with the counter not. when i run it i get a error like "the object was not found on the computer". could this be because its RDS not TS running ?

Comment: it's fine i found a other solution. the terminal server was to slow anyway :). thank you

Answer (score 0):

Sorry about that. I guess it requires Terminal Server for that perf counter to be present. I tested on Windows 11.

You could try this approach and see if that works.

```
quser | ConvertFrom-String -PropertyNames USERNAME,SESSIONNAME,ID,STATE,"IDLE TIME","LONG TIME" | Where-Object {$_.State -like "ACTIVE"} | Measure-Object | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Count
```

It would be helpful to know if you are on Windows Desktop / Server/ MAC / Linux and what PowerShell version you are using.

Comment: i would run the script on a windows server 2016 with remotedesktop rolle installed.so windows powershell version 5.1 . thank you